# The $\mathcal H^{N-1}$ measure of the projection of a curve is always less then itself

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\Gamma \subset \mathbb R^N$ be a $\mathcal H^{N-1}$-[rectifiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifiable_set) set such that $\mathcal H^{N-1}(\Gamma)<\infty$.

Let $P(\Gamma)$ be the projection of $\Gamma$ onto the hyperplane $\{x_N=0\}$. I am trying to prove that 
$$
\mathcal H^{N-1}(P(\Gamma))\leq \mathcal H^{N-1}(\Gamma)
$$
I think it is true, at least for some easy geometry it is easy to see... But I don't know how to prove it in general...

Any help is really welcome!

---

PS: I don't think rectifiable is useful here. But I have it anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the following lemma:

> If $f$ is a Lipschitz map with Lipschitz constant $L$, then $\mathcal{H}^s(fE) \le L^s \mathcal{H}^s(E)$ for all $s$.

This follows in a couple lines from the definition of Hausdorff measure: Take a cover $\{E_i\}$ of $E$ and notice that $fE_i$ is a cover and
$$\operatorname{diam}(fE_i) \le L \operatorname{diam} E_i$$

For a reference, this is Mattila chapter 7 or somewhere in Falconer.

Comment: Thx. But can you be more specifically about which Mattila's book? Thank you!

Comment: and also, the projection operator is lipschitz with lipschitz constant less than one. Do you have a reference for this? Thank you!

Comment: "Geometry of sets and measures in Euclidean space." The projection operator has Lipschitz constant exactly $1$; this is a fairly straightforward application of the definitions - just write out a point $x$ (and compute its norm), and then write out $Px$ and its norm.